# What if your server REALLY wants chmod to be 777 within a Wordpress install?

Tags: wordpress, chmod, 777

I've just found out that a server I am working on *really* wants chmod permissions to be set to 777, on quite a lot of WordPress files. This feels very unsafe to me, but there is simply no way around it.

I know 777 doesn't generally mean it's always insecure, but I believe within a Wordpress install this actually *is* the case.

I've noticed it's impossible to update plug-ins and wordpress itself when permissions aren't set to 777 for files in wp-admin etc., so the only solution I can think of now is to set them to 777 ***temporarily*** and after the updates set them back to 755 and 644. But I don't know if that reversion will make the uploading of images impossible for my editor, etc.

I wonder if there is anyone else out there who also has a server that won't eat anything lower than 777, and how they got around it.

So far my 'temporary setting' seems the only solution?

Comment: Usually a file permissions conflict is caused by your hosting provider.  I would ask them if there is any way to modify your files with a 755 instead of 777.

Comment: Not a definitive answer, if your webserver can edit files only in 777 this means the owner of the file is different than the apache/php user. 

Make sure your site is the effective owner of the files, if you have SSH access to the server this can be done with `chown`

Comment: Okay, thank you - so I'll contact my host to see what they say.